# How do I use a HTML link to navigate to a frame in a flash movie?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript

How do I externally link to a moment in the flash movie? I have three buttons that mark segments in the movie. I see that you can add actionscript code in the frame. I want to externally link to one of the sections. Thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What version Actionscript are you using? I think you need to add some functionality in your flash movie to make an external link work.

Comment: I am loading a swf animation file directly from my browser using its URL (i.e. http://mydomain.com/animation.swf). I am looking to set the frame when I load the file (if possible, with no HTML page), as in http://mydomain.com/animation.swf?frame=25. Is this possible? If so, what do I need in the URL (a bookmarlet, parameter value, etc) and what do I need inside the swf (AS3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExternalInterface is what you need:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

What you could do if you load the SWF directly into the iframe like:
`<iframe src="mydomain.com/animation.swf?frame=25"></iframe>` then you can get those parameters out of the url by putting this in your Actionscript:

```
var params:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
if(params && params.frame){
    gotoAndStop(params.frame);
}
```

You can put other parameters in there too if you want but you need to change your code for that to handle them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, found the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer to this one, pretty simple too! I paced this in the first frame. This allows us to get to a frame from an outside call. http://www.yourfile.swf?frame=25

gotoAndStop( loaderInfo.parameters.frame );
stop();